# Visual Studio 2017 release 15.7.3 does not launch application successfully

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I have a fairly standard web application with a single HELLO WORLD aspx test page, so for the purposes of this question, that is the start page.

When I run the app from visual studio by pressing f5 I get "Cannot reach this page" or whatever the 404 equivalent is in each browser. (chrome: "this site can't be reached"). In firefox, the page runs successfully first time, firefox doesn't have any debugger attachment add ins, so the problem seems to relate to debugger attachment in IIS express

If I wait a few seconds, and then F5 the browser (IE or chrome), the expected page loads successfully, so it seems to be a delay in IIS starting when a debugger is attached.

I'm wondering if anyone else has hit this and whether they have a solution. We have a quite a few tweaks in web.config to meet high security needs but otherwise I can't think why it would go wrong.

Workaround is to wait a few seconds and press f5, but thats kind of annoying when you're trying to get on with things.

Comment: I've never experienced this with a standard ASP .NET web application. I think the problem lies in your `aspx` page. Typically with ASP .NET the page will just be 'loading' until the JIT compiler does its thing - once the page is accessible Chrome will stop loading and display the page. What you're describing sounds like something else. Does your test application use a database at all?

Comment: No, its just a HELLO WORLD page, thats all it has is <body>HELLO WORLD</body>. The problem has only appeared since I installed the 15.7.3 patch late last week

Comment: Just a long-shot - but try going to Tools, Options, Debugging, and de-selecting "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET"

Comment: Wow that worked ! I've no idea how that became unticked, perhaps the installer did it. I've not been into options for a few weeks. If you'd like to paste that into the answer box I'll mark it as the answer - THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1):

As described by O.H., and verified by user2728841, the solution for me was:

Tools > Options > Debugging and *changing* "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET".

However, opposite to O.H. and like user2728841, my option was deselected, and selecting it solved the problem.